# In ISO C++, what if a source file contain a character which does not have a universal name? in Phase 1

Tags: c++, unicode

As stated in **Phases of translation**

> Physical source file characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the basic source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. The set of physical source file characters accepted is implementation-defined. Trigraph sequences (2.4) are replaced by corresponding single-character internal representations. Any source file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character.

src file chars are mapped to basic source character set in an impl-def way, I clearly know it. "*Any source file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character*" , what should I do when I'm supposed to accept a character which is not UNICODE character? Should I map it to a single basic character set member or to a universal character name(futhurmore, convert it to basic source chars seq "/uxxxxx"), both in myown manner? the latter, as I know , is not refered in standard.

Comment: If this is a comment character, it doesn't matter.  If it is in a string literal, you can do what you like so long as end up in the string literal in the way that users will expect.  If it is not in either of these places, it is soon going to be a syntax error (so you just need a good error message).  Don't forget there is a large chunk of Private Use Unicode space you could use.

Comment: What are you using as your basic source character set?

Comment: do you mean that I should map it to unversal name?

Comment: basic source chracter set is finited set which has been specified in standard 兄弟，基本源字符集就是标准规定的那些

Comment: @ChungkingExpress: "*what should I do when I'm supposed to accept a character which is not UNICODE character?*" Who are "you" in this? Because the standard is talking about the behavior of the *compiler* when reading your source code. Unless you are writing a compiler, you don't get to "map" it to anything. Also, I'm curious to know what characters are you working with that are missing from Unicode?

Comment: I'm trying to write a vvvvvvvvvvvery universal and standard compiler :)

Comment: however, it might be an over design behaviour but I just want the rational